# Blender says its out of memory when I try and change to a rendered viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

So I am doing a animation for school and am currently working on the scene for the entire animation. My problem is that whenever I try and change to a rendered view port (in cycles render), the software says that it is out of memory (I have the render set to supported - CPU). The same thing also happened when I tried to straight up render the whole scene. I don't believe it has anything to do with the hardware of the computer as it has a dedicated Nivea GeForce GTX 850M with 2 GB of memory and an i7 core processor. I really want to finish this project as I want to use it for my end of the year project that my school requires us to do, so if anyone can give me some advice, it would be most appreciated. I may have also forgot to mention that I am using Blender 2.78c.

Comment: Suggest you reduce the size of your sampling - both preview and render. Eventually reduce the dimension output. You can always turn it up later to explore the limits of your system. Maybe post your settings so other can help judge?

Comment: I don't know how complex your scene is, but if you really only have 2 GB of memory, it could just be that your computer can't handle your scene.